# Using @Component for bean throws error. NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring

I'm trying to create a simple spring app, but when i use @Component annotation for a bean instead of defining it in spring.xml file, I'm getting this error.

> Aug 09, 2017 11:06:03 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>   INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@7e32c033: startup date [Wed Aug 09 11:06:03 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   Aug 09, 2017 11:06:03 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'oval' available
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
>       at org.sumit.javabrains.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:24)

My Classes are al follows:
1. DrawingApp.java (main class)

```
public package org.sumit.javabrains;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DrawingApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    Oval oval = (Oval) context.getBean("oval");
    oval.draw();                
    }
}
```

2. Spring.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.sumit.javabrains" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="focus" class="org.sumit.javabrains.Point" scope="singleton">
    <property name="x" value="-7" />
    <property name="y" value="8" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

3 Point.java

```
package org.sumit.javabrains;
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

4 Oval.java

```
package org.sumit.javabrains;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Oval {
    private Point focus;

    public Point getFocus() {
        return focus;
    } 

    @Resource
    public void setFocus(Point focus) {
        this.focus = focus;
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Point focus is: ("+focus.getX()+", "+focus.getY()+")");     
    }
}
```

could someone be able to help what caused this issue. I'm using spring 4.3.10 RELEASE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because your component scan is scanning the wrong packages

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.sumit.javabrains" />` - **Wrong**

It should be scanning as follows:

`<context:component-scan base-package="org.sumit.javabrains" />` - **Correct**

Comment: @Alberto if this worked for you, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: For fixing a typo?

Comment: If it's a valid answer, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

you must define  all your bean in spring.xml. in this scenario you missed the Oval  class  in you  spring configuration files. define the Oval class as a bean in your spring.xml file. 
 or 
edit your component-scan tag and put the correct package.

Answer (score 1):

Two thing went wrong here.
1. You've mentioned wrong base package in your xml file

com.sumit.javabrains must be replaced with org.sumit.javabrains

2. Replace @Resource with @Resource @Qualifier("focus").By default beans marked with ‘@Component’ will have the same name as the class

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@ComponentScan` instead of `@Component` on top of the `Oval` class.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using a spring.xml file (just the default spring boot configuration instead), my @SpringBootApplication annotated class was one package level deeper than my @Component class, which made that the @Component class wasn't picked up.

E.g.:

```
com.company.base/ComponentAnnotatedClass.java
com.company.base.application/MySpringBootApplication.java
```